# c# Ftp file Upload Async | Sync

Tags: asynchronous

I've asp.net web API which upload some specific documents from end users to FTP file location on the server.
the website is public and will have many concurrent users, so many uploads can be invoked .

I want to tell user that the upload is success or fails.

I'm using the following code to upload

```
            FtpWebRequest clsRequest = (FtpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(fileName);
            clsRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
            clsRequest.Method = Ftp.UploadFile;
            using (System.IO.Stream clsStream = clsRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                clsStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                clsStream.Close();
                clsStream.Dispose();
            }
```

the code is running but I'm afraid the performance and stability with concurrent users
What's the best way from performance ,stability,and server health with concurrent users and with return success / Failure for each user

Do I need to use Async calls instead and how code should be changed?

Thanks

Comment: To write in `async` way, just change `clsRequest.GetRequestStream()` to `await clsRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync()` and `clsStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);` to `await clsStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`. Remember your method must be marked with `async` keyword and returns a `Task` if it is a void method.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a client side code. Making it async doesn`t affect server side performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot But if it will not affect performance what is the purpose or benefits of using async write

Comment: It affects clients performance. The running thread will be released and will come back after I/O interrupts (in your case, network response).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the async version of your code:

```
FtpWebRequest clsRequest = (FtpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(fileName);
clsRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
clsRequest.Method = Ftp.UploadFile;
using (System.IO.Stream clsStream = await clsRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
{
    await clsStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    // These lines not required since they are located inside using statement.
    //clsStream.Close();
    //clsStream.Dispose();
}
```

Remember your method must be marked with async keyword and returns a Task if it is a void method. Also, I have to mention that this is a client-side code. Making it async doesn`t affect server-side performance.